# Javascript Proxies and With statements

Tags: javascript

Why does this throw a ReferenceError?

```
var p = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function(target, name) {
        return `hello world ${name}`;
    }
});
with (p) { console.log(a) }
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

Comment: You are trying to run `console.log(a)` but you never defined `a`. I'm assuming you mean to run `console.log(p)`.

Comment: While this may work somehow, dont do this!

Comment: @dave yes, its "hello world a"

Comment: @Santi: The idea is that his proxy should catch property access, and `with` should be trying to access `a` from `p`. So somewhere in the semantics of `with` or proxies, this is prevented.

Comment: What's less clear here is why you'd **ever** do this...

Comment: @JaredSmith: This could be an interesting way of locating access to undeclared variables at the global level at runtime when you can't rely on strict mode being present. Make a proxy for `window`, then `with (w_prox) { ...application code... }`

Comment: ...and actually, if `with` is already being used for another purpose, you'd get a similar benefit of being able to avoid such reference errors and log the invalid access. I'm starting to think that they should perhaps alter `with` to accommodate this.

Comment: @spanky that may be fine and dandy if you're writing an JS interpreter or code executor that may be fed invalid input, but has no place in production code. Nor is the TC-39 likely to expand the functionality of a known-bugged and deprecated feature (throws in strict mode).

Answer (score 9):

This code is very silly. However the question it raises is very interesting. It turns out you can get this to work! You need a way to tell javascript what variables are available in the object using the `has` method on a proxy. Furthermore for some reason symbols cannot be implicitly converted to string. So in order to get this code to "*Work*" you need something like this.

```
var p = new Proxy({}, {
    //we need to identify what elements are available. 
    //this overloads the in operator eg ("foo" in obj)
    has:function(target,name){
        //if we just returned true we would override everything
        //and we need to get to the console
        return name!="console";
    },      
    get: function(target, name) {
        //for some reason the toString is mandatory don't know why 
        //you get "TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string" otherwise
        return "Hello world "+name.toString();
    }
});
with (p) { console.log(abc) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `with` probably reads the existing properties of the `p` object and adds them to the variable scope. So since there's no actual `a` property, it doesn't get added to the scope.

In other words, the `a` lookup at that point invokes variable resolution, and never invokes property resolution.

[13.11 With Statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-with-statement)

> The with statement adds an object Environment Record for a computed object to the lexical environment of the running execution context. It then executes a statement using this augmented lexical environment. Finally, it restores the original lexical environment.

Then in variable resolution, it performs a `hasBinding(name)`, which will fail for the proxy object, because there is no binding.

[8.1.1 Environment Records](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-environment-records)

> HasBinding(N)  Determine if an Environment Record has a binding for the String value N. Return true if it does and false if it does not